# How can I select multiple sibblings CSS classes without repeating full path?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to simplyfy this:

```
div.container>table>tbody>tr>td h1,
div.container>table>tbody>tr>td h2,
div.container>table>tbody>tr>td h3{
    color: red;
}
```

to get something like this?

```
div.container>table>tbody>tr>td (h1, h2, h3){
    color: red;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible with [`SASS`](http://sass-lang.com/)

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/063e4x7g/1/

```
.container tr td {
  h1, h2, h3 {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma separated is the only way,

but there is another option which will select all the parent`s childs:

```
div.container>table>tbody>tr>td>* {
    color: red;
}
```

however i do not recommend using this.

Answer (score 0):

```
table h1, 
table h2,
table h3 {
 color: red;
}
```

check out fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/g158jr8v/